# How do you make a discord bot that send a message if another user send a message? discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Hi I need help in making a bot that can send a message if a specific user send one.

ex.
Arikakate: hi guys
Bot: yo wassup

this is the code i managed to write but doesn't work:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    me = '<user id>'
    if message.author.id == me:
        await message.channel.send("yo wassup")
    else:
        return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because the ID's are integers, also `message.author` can be `None` if you don't have `intents.members` enabled

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    me = 6817239871982378981
    if message.author.id == me:
        await message.channel.send('yo wassup')
```

**What are `intents`?**

Discord requires users to declare what sort of information (i.e. events) they will require for their bot to operate. This is done via form of intents.
*You can read more about intents [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)*

**What are privileged intents?**

With the API change requiring bot authors to specify intents, some intents were restricted further and require more manual steps. These intents are called **privileged intents.**

**How do I enable intents?**

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()

bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
# or if you're using `discord.Client`
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

**How do I enable privileged intents**?

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all() # If you want both members and presences

# if you only want members or presences
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

Also make sure to enable privileged member intents in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications). [here's how](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents)

Comment: wait so i change the variable me to a string and i don't understand the second part you said.

Comment: no, you change the `me` variable to an integer. I'll edit my answer explaining what are intents and how you should enable them.

Comment: Each user has their own ID. You can find this by going on Discord in developer mode and right-clicking on a user. There will be a button that says Copy ID. Developer Mode is at the bottom of the Appearance tab in the Discord settings. For example, my ID is 348311499946721282.

Comment: ok, i have changed the **me** variable to an int. i have also enabled intents. now my code is:


`@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    me = 767208094525947924
    if message.author.id == me:
        await message.channel.send("yo wassup")
    else:
        return `

Comment: sorry it looks messed up, i will answer my question with the code

Comment: also i have another question. when we enable intent. the 3 dots after `bot = commands.Bot` what does that stand for?

Comment: IT WORKED!! Thanks so much for the help. Also I tried to use my command but everytime i type it it send the message ***yo wassup** how do i look for my command prefix in the message the user sent?

Comment: You can use a command if you're using `commands.Bot`, if not `message.content.startswith('prefix')`

Answer (score 1):

Creating a command that checks if the author of the message id is '2130947502309247'.

If it isn't the bot sends a message that says "That id does not belong to you", if the id does belong to the author the bot says "That id belong to you"

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id != 2130947502309247:
        await ctx.send("That id does not belong to you")
    else:
        await ctx.send("That id belong to you")
```

Quite simple

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please give a idea, what your code is doing.

Comment: My code is creating a command that checks if the author of the message id is 2130947502309247. If it isn't the bot sends a message that says "That id does not belong to you", if the id does belong to the author the bot says ""That id belong to you"

Comment: Please edit your answere and write it there :)

Comment: You mean write in the answere what i wrote in the comment?

Comment: Yes. I did it for you.